# A question about simple circles and triangles

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Today I've encountered a question like the following I am adding a picture because I have to;

[image]

The question paragraph says;

$\text{Given} \quad |OF|=6 \quad \text{and} \quad |BF|=4$

What is $|CH|=x$

**My Attempts;**

I have noticed that the diameter $r=10$ (1)

I have drawn a line from $C$ to $O$ which also is $r$ (2)

I have written $|HO|=\sqrt{100-x^2}$ but couldn't go further,

What do you suggest?

Comment: How about $\angle EOF$?

Comment: Do you imply that it is $90^\circ$? It didn't work $8$ is the wrong answer:(

Comment: Do you mean the diameter or the radius is 10?

Comment: $|OB|=10$ so $|OC|=10$ too, was the diameter $2r$ or $r$ I probably remembered it wrongly.

Comment: Something more is needed here. Is it also given that EC=ED=EF, as marked in the figure?

Comment: I made no changes in The paragraph I originally received I  think The same way as you do. But I suppose The marked ones are equal

Comment: And also is it a good idea to draw a line from $H$ to $E$. Since we know that $|HE|$ is equal to The marked ones.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha=\angle HFC$ and $a=EF$, so that $x=2a\sin\alpha$.

From the cosine law applied to triangle $OFC$ we get:
$$
OF^2+FC^2-2OF\cdot FC\cos\alpha=OC^2,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
a^2-6a\cos\alpha=16.
$$

From the cosine law applied to triangle $OFD$ (notice that $FD=\sqrt2a$) we get:
$$
OF^2+FD^2-2OF\cdot FD\cos(\pi/4+\alpha)=OD^2,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
a^2-6a\cos\alpha+6a\sin\alpha=32.
$$
Substituting here our previous result we thus get $6a\sin\alpha=16$, that is $x=2a\sin\alpha={16\over3}$.

Comment: Is it ODF instead of EFD and I got lost in The part where you said $\cos(\pi/4+\alpha)$ why added $\alpha$. Excuse me for my ignorance and many thanks for this elegant solution:))

Comment: @Deniz: $\angle DFE=\pi/4$ from triangle $EFD$

Comment: $\angle OFD=\angle OFE+\angle EFD=\alpha+\pi/4$. And then you need of course the [cosine addition formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html).

Comment: I know the cosine sum formula, but I carelessly thought that $\pi/4=90^\circ$ I then realised it was $45^\circ$, thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution, because I get the results using analytic geometry

Anyway I hope it can be useful

[image]

Comment: Which software do you use to draw these figures?

Comment: @MathLover GeoGebra at https://www.geogebra.org/ 

It is much much more than a tool for drawing!

Comment: Thanks @Raffaele.